# Win11 Experts: Keyboard Shortcut to Move Windows to Other Monitor?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

So I've been using Windows 11 for a good while now and one thing that bothers me about it is how many common keyboard shortcuts no longer work. (ALT+2 to create new folders, for one, but also some others.)

The one I consistently miss the most is the shortcut to move windows from one monitor to another (WIN + Shift + Left/Right). I've searched on Google for this and I haven't been able to find a solution--are classic keyboard shortcuts an option we can enable somewhere in Explorer? Or is there something specific with this one?

Comment: Win left and right kinda still work, just aerosnaps to one side then goes?

Comment: Is your desktop in Extended mode over both monitors?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek mine doesn't even do that, which is a little odd

Comment: @harrymc yup. I've tried with windows that are on both monitors and no matter which monitor we're starting with they won't move. (Unless I click and drag the old-fashioned way of course.)